# 1 error prohibited this article from being saved:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Error prohibited this article from being saved:
Author must exist

My article.rb code

first i make articles table, then i make authors table, next i added reference to article

My article.rb code

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :author
end
```

Schema.rb

```
create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "judul_artikel"
t.text "konten"
t.integer "category_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.integer "authors_id"
t.index ["authors_id"], name: "index_articles_on_authors_id"
t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_articles_on_category_id"
end

create_table "authors", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "author_name"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "nama_kategori"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

end
```

I just want to create article but there is no error telling this. how i fix this?

Comment: Can you add your article creating controller code ? I think error is because either author or category is not going with article.

Comment: i have fixed this, the problem is when i add_references :articles, :authors to add_references :articles, :author